# Add multiple suffixes to AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am configuring a Lambda function that should take .png and .pdf files from my bucket.
How can I provide Lambda config with multiple suffixes?

Here is what I want to do:

[image]

Please advise how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it may seen from the tooltip description; you can't set multiple suffixes on aws console.

> Enter a `single` optional suffix to limit the notifications to objects with keys that end with matching characters.

What you may do is to create multiple triggers and define each suffix in a separate s3 trigger.

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) has some sample xml configuration to support multiple/non-overlapping suffix/prefix options but i think it is not possible to set them on web console.